# How to plot discrete data on the cross-section of 3D graph in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot discrete data written in stp199inf2.dat on the cross-section at z=0, where functions c1 and c2 are also drawn.
I really need help now.

---

```
set multiplot

c1(x,y) = x**2 + y**2 -1 - 0.1*cos(16*atan(x/y))
c2(x,y) = (x-0.5)**2 + (y-0.5)**2 -0.5

C=0.7
set xrange[0:1.2]
set yrange[0:1.2]

set tics font"Times New Roman,12"
set xlabel "f1"
set ylabel "f2"
set xlabel font "Times New Roman, 12"
set ylabel font "Times New Roman, 12"
set key font "Times New Roman, 12"
set key right top

set isosamples 300,300
set contour base
set cntrparam levels discrete  0.0
set nosurface
set size square
set view 0,0,

splot c1(x,y)  lt -1 lw 1 title ""
splot c2(x,y) lt -1 lw 1 title ""
splot c1(x,y) lt 3 lw 2.5 title "True Pareto Front"

splot './gnuplot_plot/stp199inf2.dat' lt 4 ps 3 pt 7 

pause -1
```

-------------------stp199inf2.dat----------------------

```
1.037663 0.042694 0.0
0.071479 1.018838 0.0
0.871717 0.475405 0.0
0.909571 0.456881 0.0
0.996505 0.096337 0.0
```

---

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question? Can you explain what result you get from your code and how that is different from what you expect? Maybe you can upload a figure somewhere and share a link here?

Answer (score 0):

With the `unset surface` also the points aren't drawn. So you must set the surface before plotting the points.

Some other remarks to your code:

1. If you have everything in a single plot you should use a single `splot` command with comma-delimited calls.
2. In that case you must unset the surface for the first three plot with the option `nosurface`.
3. You must unset the contours for the point plot with the option `nocontour`.
4. If you use `set view map` instead of `set view 0,0`, the overlapping zticlabels aren' drawn.

So, a reasonable script could look like:

```
set termoption font"Times New Roman,12"
set multiplot

c1(x,y) = x**2 + y**2 -1 - 0.1*cos(16*atan(x/y))
c2(x,y) = (x-0.5)**2 + (y-0.5)**2 -0.5

C=0.7
set xrange[0:1.2]
set yrange[0:1.2]

set xlabel "f1"
set ylabel "f2"
set key outside

set isosamples 300,300
set contour base
set cntrparam levels discrete  0.0
set size square
set view map

splot c1(x,y)  lt -1 lw 1 title "" nosurface,\
      c2(x,y) lt -1 lw 1 title "" nosurface,\
      c1(x,y) lt 3 lw 2.5 title "True Pareto Front" nosurface,\
      'stp199inf2.dat' lt 4 ps 3 pt 7 nocontour title ""

unset multiplot
```

The output with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

I'm not sure, how to best handle the contour key entries. I'll update the answer when I find something.